# Angular 7 and Data sources a field is not iterable inside a loop but can be found if the whole array is consoled

Tags: angular, datasource, angular7

I have the following method which return a number, and if this number is bigger than 0, it will forbid a specific action:

```
checkAdded(name, forType, type) {
  name = this.pipe.transform(name);
  let count = 0;
  if (type == "situation") {
    Object.keys(this.dataSource3).forEach((key, index) => {
      //console.log('Sit '+this.dataSource3.filteredData[index]['situation_type']+ ' '+name);
      //console.log('Sit '+this.dataSource3.filteredData[index]['situation_for']+' '+forType);
      if (this.dataSource3.filteredData[index]['situation_type'] == name && this.dataSource3.filteredData[index]['situation_for'] == forType) {
        count++;
        //console.log(count)
      }
    })
  }


    if (type == "legal") {
    Object.keys(this.dataSource2).forEach((key, index) => {
      console.log(this.dataSource2.filteredData[index]['legal_name']);
      //console.log('L '+this.dataSource2.filteredData[index]['legal_name']+ ' '+name);
      //console.log('L '+this.dataSource2.filteredData[index]['legal_for']+' '+forType);
      if (this.dataSource2.filteredData[index]['legal_name'] == name && this.dataSource2.filteredData[index]['legal_for'] == forType) {
        count++;
        console.log(count)
      }
    })
  }
  if (type == "protection") {
    Object.keys(this.dataSource).forEach((key, index) => {
      if (this.dataSource.filteredData[index]['protection_name'] == name && this.dataSource.filteredData[index]['protection_for'] == forType) {
        count++;
        //console.log(count);
      }
    })
  }
  //console.log(count)
  return count;
}
```

If the user click on the button, specified for types `situation` and `protection`, the `checkAdded()` will work properly.

But if the type is `legal`, the add button will throw the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'legal_name' of undefined
>       at protection.component.ts:162
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at...

The datasources are:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<GetProtection[]>();
dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource<GetLegal[]>();
dataSource3 = new MatTableDataSource<GetSituation[]>();

export interface GetProtection {
  protection_name: string;
  protection_date_added: string;
  protection_status: string;
  protection_for: number;

}
export interface GetLegal {
  legal_name: string;
  legal_date_added: string;
  legal_status: string;
  legal_for: number;

}
export interface GetSituation {
  situation_name: string;
  situation_date_added: string;
  situation_status: string;
  situation_for: number;

}
```

If I console the following:

```
if (type == "legal") {
    Object.keys(this.dataSource2).forEach((key, index) => {
      console.log(this.dataSource2.filteredData[index]['legal_name']);
      if (this.dataSource2.filteredData[index]['legal_name'] == name && this.dataSource2.filteredData[index]['legal_for'] == forType) {
        count++;
        //console.log(count)
      }
    })
  }
```

It will iterate all the possible values of `legal_name`:

[image]

So the iteration is happening, but inside the `if` condition, it can't find `legal_name` in the array.

If I console `this.dataSource2` just before doing the iteration, it will display all the array:

[image].

There is method, setting all three `dataSources` on component load:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(Object.values(data));
this.dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource(Object.values(data2));
this.dataSource3 = new MatTableDataSource(Object.values(data3));
```

**EDIT**

Could I use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/every) in case of `type == 'legal'`? But the code will be like using multiple method for the same reason.

Comment: may be when user clicked type="legal" the value of datasource2 is altered somewhere in yours code . just add debugger inside that method and check datasource2 value

Comment: also yours "GetLegal"  model not contains field"legal_name" , You're assigning dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource<GetLegal[]>();

Comment: @BhagvatLande it do contain `export interface GetLegal {
  legal_name: string;`

Comment: Your code seems correct, but maybe you do not look at the right place: your console.log is at line 154 whereas your error is at line 162.

Comment: I am consoling outside the `if` and the error is directly on the `if` statement. And if you compare the `if` of all types, it is the same @Mic

Comment: The break point gave the error at after the iteration has been completed on the array @Mic

Comment: Can you `console.log(Object.keys(this.dataSource2))`. I suspect that your the length of this array is more than the number of elements in your `filteredData` array.

Comment: @MM there is an `undefined` array but that does not exist in the database where I am getting the array from.

Comment: Not sure @alim1990. can you show us the `console.log(Object.keys(this.dataSource2))`. May be we can help then.